# You're a Romanizer, Baby

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language

Romanization of Japanese is converting Japanese text into Latin characters. In this challenge, you will be given a string of Japanese characters as input and expected to convert them to the correct ASCII string.

## What You'll Need To Know

The Japanese language has three writing systems: hiragana (the curvy one used for short words), katakana (the angle-y one used for sounds and words borrowed from other langauges), and kanji (the dense characters originally from Chinese). In this challenge we will only worry about hiragana.

There are 46 characters in the hiragana syllabary. Each character represents a syllable. The characters are organized by first sound (consonant) and second sound (vowel). The columns in order are `aiueo`.

```
 : あいうえお
k: かきくけこ
s: さしすせそ
t: たちつてと
n: なにぬねの
h: はひふへほ
m: まみむめも
y: や　ゆ　よ
r: らりるれろ
w: わ　　　を
N: ん
```

(if you copy and paste this table note that I have used ideographic spaces U+3000 to space out y and w)

So, for instance, あとめ should produce an output of `atome`. The first character is `a`, the second is `to`, and the third is `me`.

## Exceptions

Like any good language, Japanese has exceptions to its rules, and the hiragana table has several. These characters are pronounced slightly differently than their location in the table would imply:

し: `shi`, not `si`
ち: `chi`, not `ti`
つ: `tsu`, not `tu`
ふ: `fu`, not `hu`

## Dakuten ゛

The word 'dakuten' means 'muddy mark': the dakuten turns sounds into their voiced equivalents (usually); for example, か `ka` turns into か゛ `ga`. A full list of the changes:

`k` → `g`
`s` → `z`
`t` → `d`
`h` → `b`

The exceptions change too:
し゛: `ji` (or `zhi`), not `zi`
ち゛: `ji`, not `di`
つ゛: `dzu`, not `du`
(ふ゛ acts as you would expect; it is not an exception)

The handakuten is an *additional* character ゜ that applies to the `h` row. If placed after a character, it changes the character's sound to `p` rather than `b`.

Both the dakuten and handakuten are going to be given as individual characters. You will not need to deal with the precomposed forms or the combining characters.

## Small Characters

Finally, there are small versions of some of the characters. They modify characters that come before or after them.

ゃゅょ

These are the small forms of `ya`, `yu`, and `yo`. They are only placed after sounds in the `i`-column; they remove the `i` and add their sound. So, きや turns into `kiya`; きゃ turns into `kya`.

If placed after `chi` or `shi` (or their dakuten-ed forms), the `y` is removed too.  しゆ is `shiyu`; しゅ is `shu`.

The last thing you'll have to deal with is the small `tsu`. っ doubles the consonant that comes after it, no matter what; it does nothing else. For instance, きた is `kita`; きった is `kitta`.

## Summary, Input, and Output

Your program must be able to transliterate: the 46 basic hiragana, their dakuten and handakuten forms, and their combinations with small characters.

Undefined behavior includes: small `ya`, `yu`, and `yo` not after a character with `i`, small `tsu` at the end of a string, dakuten on an unaffected character, handakuten on a non-`p` character, and anything else not mentioned in the above spec/introduction.

You may assume all inputs are valid and contain only the Japanese characters mentioned above.

Case does not matter in output; you may also replace `r` with `l` or a lone `n` with `m`. Output can have either one space between every syllable or no spaces at all.

**This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf): shortest code in bytes wins.**

## Test Cases

Many test cases for each individual part are given in the spec. Some additional cases:

ひらか゛な → `hiragana`

かたかな → `katakana`

た゛いき゛ゃくてんさいは゛ん → `daigyakutensaiban`

ふ゜ろく゛らみんく゛は゜す゛るこうと゛こ゛るふ → `puroguramingupazurucoudogorufu`

か゛んほ゛って → `ganbatte`

## Notes

- I do not know much Japanese besides what I've written here. Please let me know if I've made any mistakes.
- I was originally planning to include katakana too (so my English transliteration test case could be *slightly* more accurate), but that would be too much for a code golf challenge.
- The Unicode names include the transliteration of each character individually, but without the exceptions. This may or may not be helpful to you.
- Thanks to squeamishossifrage for correcting two typos!
- I'm sorry if this is too long; I attempted to fit most of the quirks of hiragana into the challenge but some things (like small vowel-only hiragana, changing n to m in front of some consonants, and the repetition mark) had to be cut to keep the challenge manageable.
- I'm not at all sorry for the title. It's a masterpiece.

Comment: What should be the output for `きっった`?

Comment: @Thomas: That's an invalid input. Output can be whatever you want.

Comment: should `っし` be `sshi` or `shshi`?

Comment: @Thomas: It shouls be `sshi`.

Comment: Romanization is converting any non-Latin text into Latin characters.

Comment: Should the programs support ーs? For example: こーどごるふ?

Comment: @ConfusedMr_C: No need; AFAIK that's only (or at least *mostly*) used with katakana.

Comment: True enough, but you specified that katakana should be written as hiragana, so コードゴルフ should be こーどごるふ, correct?

Comment: @Mr_C: Hm? I don't quite understand. I said your program only had to support hiragana; the program does not have to know the rules of Japanese besides the ones mentioned in the spec.

Comment: @Desuovi: Oh, okay. Just leaving out support for ー is okay then?

Comment: @Mr_C: Yeah, you don't need to support ー at all. In my test case I specifically used こうと゛こ゛るふ rather than こーどごるふ because as far as I know using ー with hiragana is extremely uncommon.

Comment: `I'm not at all sorry for the title. It's a masterpiece.` Downvoted

Comment: @Fatalize No need to bring your anti-Britney bias here. Even though I may personally be more of a J-Lo fan, I'm not gonna downvote an excellent puzzle over that.

Comment: It's never `zhi`, while `zi` is standard for _kunrei-shiki_.

Comment: The last test case is incorrect, it should be `ganbOtte` vs `ganbAtte`.

Answer (score 7):

## Python 2, 638 bytes

```python
import unicodedata
s=input()
k=[0x309B,0x309C,0x3063]
m=[0x3083,0x3085,0x3087]
e={0x3057:'shi',0x3061:'chi',0x3064:'tsu',0x3075:'fu'}
d={0x3057:'ji',0x3061:'ji',0x3064:'dzu'}
D=dict(zip('ksth','gzdb'))
f=lambda c:unicodedata.name(c).split()[-1].lower()if ord(c)not in e else e[ord(c)]
g=lambda c:d[c]if c in d else D[f(c)[0]]+f(c)[1:]
R=[]
r=[]
t=[]
i=0
while i<len(s):
 c=ord(s[i])
 if c==k[0]:R[-1]=g(s[i-1])
 elif c==k[1]:R[-1]='p'+R[-1][1:]
 elif c in m:R[-1]=R[-1][:-1];n=f(s[i]);R+=[n[1:]]if r[-1]in[0x3057,0x3061]else[n];r+=[c]
 elif c==k[2]:t+=[len(R)]
 else:R+=[f(s[i])];r+=[c]
 i+=1
for i in t:R[i]=R[i][0]+R[i]
print ''.join(R)
```

Takes input as unicode string.

Test it on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/Brx4nZ)

Comment: You can save a measly bye by changing `print ''.join(R)` to `print''.join(R)`

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2, 447 bytes

```python
import unicodedata as u
r=str.replace
i=''.join('x'*('SM'in u.name(x)or ord(x)==12444)+u.name(x)[-2:].strip()for x in raw_input().decode('utf-8'))
for a,o in zip('KSTH','GZDB'):
    for b in'AEIOU':i=r(r(i,a+b+'xRK','P'+b),a+b+'RK',o+b)
for a,b,c,d in zip('STDZ',('SH','CH','J','J'),'TDHH',('TS','DZ','F','F')):i=r(r(i,a+'I',b+'I'),c+'U',d+'U')
for a in'CH','SH','J':i=r(i,a+'IxY',a)
for a in'BCDFGHJKMNPRSTWYZ':i=r(i,'xTSU'+a,a+a)
print r(i,'Ix','')
```

This takes Unicode input directly, which made me lose a few bytes because of the `decode('utf-8')` but I think is more in the spirit of the challenge.

I began by replacing every character by the last two characters of its unicode name, as suggested in the notes of the puzzle. Unfortunately, this doesn't distinguish between alternate versions of the same character, so I had to make an ugly hack to add an 'x' before the small characters and the handakuten.

The rest of the for loops are just fixing exceptions, in order:

1. the first for loop turns dakutens and handakutens into the correct consonants;
2. the second for loop deals with the hiragana exceptions of shi, chi, tsu and fu;
3. third for loop deals with the exceptions before a small y- character (like sha, jo);
4. fourth for loop deals with doubling consonants after a small tsu.
5. final line deals with small y-.

I wish I could have combined more steps, but in some cases the steps have to be performed in order to avoid conflicts.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY7NSsNAFIX3eYrsbsZMA5YupJCFbWzTlqo0KdKKyKRJccQmYZpgdJcsBBFx0ZXoA7hz1bUPMw8SZ9IfOjA3ufd859yJn5K7KKyXJV3EEUvUNKSzyA98khCVLNVUYeYyYQYL4gcyCxRqAhj3EQ01yOBIA2cINFRTIySLQMtQxNSI@eLHNI/rjUYD6XvpulZv3hgii8YamgswU4WTkcdbGsZpoiHDD@RmDdJkXjsBhBRJERxJ7lm4YOC4NmDoTq0WoKaiiiMRTwBweta7GEOTmkxjGsVE93TIRgOBX4Luoc1A9pHotskenmF/n@641hSw@ModbVn61UUYXMu2peQ6YiIp6FQXoYOF0APsyYrwTIcxYF/W7S75xCrT2QRXvo0rmwAmB1irbXW6dn8wPL8cOe7VZLqDIXOdMehEuAQfMxomajXvZSITUFnyfM2Lb1688/yDF1@8eOX5Hy9W2zb/lWr@WUlvPBfzF57/VNJqN1z/Aw) (a multi-line version with more examples can be found [here](https://tio.run/##TVBPa9RAFD9vPsXcXsZMAy57kIUcbNd2t0u1NFmkKyLZTZaOtEmYJjT2lqiVthTBRURa8CAUoaCnnjz4YeaDrPNeuqWHeXnv/f49kr3L99KkvVjIgyxVOSsSOU2jOArzkIWHrLCYFcUzNrNz3rVayjvMlavibD@cxlZLegDu21QmNpTwyAZ/C2TCCjcJD2K75KliqYpM43mP251Ohzv30KuVdve1a8xkZvOZIZbMKHM3ijHdhiKfrTwBzq0WgqFIET42ZBj6QR8EbIx7q4AnEWFiYHj6bPBiBF3pKVvZUoTOxIFyZ2jI2@BMeLPAOTXT0ngipiK6N/eD3hiE@WLEGpZNelxA0Ov3EQp8s0EWrNPj/EEiDEBMsHIxdWAEIsK6DMMjydRvnEnYyMpdEOFD3upab32jvzncer694wcvd8dLNpSBPwInNDIUZEomOSNgUBpXE8asoz25H7NAFbH5QTNbhUdvZJIVuc35YqGrb7r@pKsTai5Nb@nqRlc/dfVX11e6npt5jghSvuvql67PCP5MQPWbtn9Ie4om1QddGfY5NTdk@9GwdXWLtf5iIYbs@Z0Mza4txDHvgliN2T8i0YjUK4xC6JyST@iYy7vzcHlrXH7QykRf0PY9RV@T0VfaN6fO/wM)).

Comment: [TIO link](https://tio.run/##TVBPS8MwFD@vnyK3l9is4NhBBj3opu4PU7Ed4kQkXVuMuLZkKVZv7UEQEQ@eRD@AN0@e/TD5IDPpnHjIS977/Xsku5WXadJaLvk8S4VEecJnaRiFTDLEFii3kBVGMYqxJB2rIdyFFI6Isms2i6wGdwGcq5QnGArYwOCNgScodxI2j3BBUoFSEeqH62622u02sf@gs2arc@5oM55hEmtigbRSOmFk0jHkMm5uASFWw4CMpga@02QYeX4fKOxPeztgVqoJgYZhe3dwOIEOdwUWmFNmBzYUxyNNPgI7IKuB6VPdrY0DOqPhn7nn96ZA9W0iuqYM60Mo@L1@30C@pyeGBXv1IeRfIgyABqYSOrNhAjQ0dR1mlqxNvZVzLVzJilOg7D9vp9vb2@8PR@ODo2PPPzmdrtlQ@N4EbKZlRpAJnkhUA4NCu@owZN1c8usI@SKP9AfFWLCbC55kucSELJeq/FLVu6qeVPmsqjdVPajyW1Uvv235adDytYYeVann96r8qKGX9fDrBw)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Very nice first solution :)

Comment: Turn your four spaces in front of `for b in'AEIOU'` into a tab or a single space to save 3 bytes. You may also be able to use `from unicodedata import*` to save some bytes - not sure.

Answer (score 6):

### Swift 3, <strike>67</strike> 64 characters

<strike>let r={(s:String) in s.applyingTransform(.toLatin, reverse: false)}</strike>

```
let r={(s:String)in s.applyingTransform(.toLatin,reverse:false)}
```

Comment: A builtin, really, Swift has a BUILTIN FOR THIS?

Comment: Don't know Swift at all, but can you chop the whitespaces after `s:String)` and `.toLatin,`?

Comment: @TuukkaX, well spotted!

Comment: @Zacharý, well `Foundation` has.

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 259 bytes

```python
import re,unicodedata as u
s=re.sub
n=u.normalize
k,*r=r'NFKC DZU DU TSU TU \1\1 SM.{6}(.) \1 (CH|J|SH)Y \1 ISMALL.(Y.) CHI TI JI [ZD]I SHI SI FU HU'.split()
t=''.join(u.name(c)[16:]for c in n(k,s(' ','',n(k,input()))))
while r:t=s(r.pop(),r.pop(),t)
print(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NVBLS@RAEL73ryjmko6EsIPgQchhmUEmvi4xBx09xJks9jrTCZ0Ovg@JL1aRAQfZlRHE9YEg6MmTB39M/5Cxu2YMlUrVV1999ZF0R24kfHIYb8ctKiqVypB100RIELGTc9ZK2nE7khFEGeQk80TsZvk64V7u8kR0ow7bjcmmMyE8YS3OzNWgvhJCPYSlQL8hrFZXqxAsuHtTB9S1dQu01tif3Q8a9rLp/GDh5/y8S5f1sNbwYcmHWR@aK/U1HwLdBz7MhNAILTdLO0xSm0jPstzfCeNUO4i6MW3ZzerU9NqvREALGAdON52MWmA5luWYhvE015vmIVsbrBODmJZeRoWbJim1ne@vtEkqGJdU2kP9H2ACqj/soSr@migHqrgzYYoHE6Z4N1EOCDIOVfEP8x3m/zoT5N6r4hHzw4h4qoqTsWZ5qqEXHH6o8kaVfd33UVtTrlXxrMozHPdwULwi@oa7f9DbkSo0@xyLF5Q91mz01lPlJTEzw@6P14zYE0Hj@t4FskZin0jC1lBvzCkzOsfLJ2hmMLZnwHetcouQPn2B6CGefkKhK8RHVvtf)

### Explanation

We’re in luck with this input format! Look what happens if I pass the input through [NFKC normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/):

```python
>>> nfkc = lambda x: u.normalize('NFKC', x)
>>> [u.name(c) for c in 'は゛']
['HIRAGANA LETTER HA', 'KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK']
>>> [u.name(c) for c in nfkc('は゛')]
['HIRAGANA LETTER HA', 'SPACE', 'COMBINING KATAKANA-HIRAGANA VOICED SOUND MARK']
```

The dakuten gets replaced by a space and a combining dakuten. Now that space is all that’s separating the は from its dakuten. So we get rid of it and normalize *again*:

```python
>>> [u.name(c) for c in nfkc(nfkc('は゛').replace(' ', ''))]
['HIRAGANA LETTER BA']
```

Bingo. The fifth line turns the input into something like

```python
KONOSUBARASIISEKAINISISMALL YUKUHUKUWO
```

Then we apply 9 boring regex substitutions crammed in `r`, and we’re done:

```python
KONOSUBARASHIISEKAINISHUKUFUKUWO
```

(Jonathan French saved 4 bytes, writing `import re,unicodedata as u` instead of `import re;from unicodedata import*`. Thanks!)

Comment: Abusing normalisation for fun and profit. That's beautiful.

Comment: `import re,unicodedata as u` as in [Kirill L. answer to a related challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/155874/73111) saves [4 bytes](https://tio.run/##NY49a8MwGIR3/Yp3k1SEwBQyBDwUm2ClSRfFQ74GxVGJGlsSkkxpm/52Vx56cBwPx8H5r3Rz9nmazOBdSBA0G63p3FVfVVKgIowolkHzOF6QLUduXRhUb741urOnUAb8tnqtoD60ULewk9ktnIpTAXLLfxa/hNOMQKrmsX7Ihu5nEnL7stlwss9l1QjYCVgLOB7qswCZWQpYtdC0mEffm0QoSiXG/MMZS/IDNWjS0WOxWJ7fXYAOjAVL7iwSDJhhzGYw1o95OQt93kyvISxTGUng3nlC2X8minwwNpFEp@kP).

Answer (score 0):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), <s>549</s> 498 bytes

Lexurgy *does* have a romanizer function that uses the rules as everything else, but it's meant more for debugging/additional output purposes and is not useful for this challenge.

```bash
Symbol sh,ch,ts
k:
{あ,い,う,え,お,か,き,く,け,こ,さ,し,す,せ,そ,た,ち,つ,て,と,な,に,ぬ,ね,の,は,ひ,ふ,へ,ほ,ま,み,む,め,も,ら,り,る,れ,ろ,や,ゆ,よ,わ,を,ん,ゃ,ゅ,ょ}=>{a,i,u,e,o,ka,ki,ku,ke,ko,sa,shi,su,se,so,ta,chi,tsu,te,to,na,ni,nu,ne,no,ha,hi,hu,he,ho,ma,mi,mu,me,mo,ra,ri,ru,re,ro,ya,yu,yo,wa,wo,n,Ya,Yu,Yo}
v:
{k,s,t,ch,ts,h,sh} []$1 ゛=>{g,z,d,j,dz,b,j} $1 *
h []$1 ゜=>p $1 *
hu=>fu
s:
iY=>* y
iY=>*/{ch,sh,j} _
っ []$1=>$1 $1
```

Ungolfed explanation:

````bash
Symbol sh, ch, ts # treat these as a single character

# unfortunate kana -> latin mappings
Class kana {あ,い,う,え,お,か,き,く,け,こ,さ,し,す,せ,そ,た,ち,つ,て,と,な,に,ぬ,ね,の,は,ひ,ふ,へ,ほ,ま,み,む,め,も,ら,り,る,れ,ろ,や,ゆ,よ,わ,を,ん,ゃ,ゅ,ょ}
Class latin {a,i,u,e,o,ka,ki,ku,ke,ko,sa,shi,su,se,so,ta,chi,tsu,te,to,na,ni,nu,ne,no,ha,hi,hu,he,ho,ma,mi,mu,me,mo,ra,ri,ru,re,ro,ya,yu,yo,wa,wo,n,Ya,Yu,Yo}
# voicing mappings
Class unvoiced {k,s,t,ch,ts,h,sh}
Class voiced {g,z,d,j,dz,b,j}

kana-to-latin:
@kana => @latin

voicing:
@unvoiced []$1 ゛ => @voiced $1 * # apply dakuden
h []$1 ゜ => p $1 * # apply handakuden

fu: # explicit exception for ふ
hu => fu

small-y: # small やゆよ
i => * / _ Y
Y => y

shyu: # handle ちぢしじ
y => * / {ch,sh,j} _

small-tsu: # gemination (duplication of a character) is the prototypical use-case for capturing
っ []$1 => $1 $1
```
````

Answer (score 0):

## Python3, 607 bytes:

```py
def f(s):
 V='aiueo'
 v,k,d,u,w,t,l,q,g,j=(t:=b.split('\n'))[0][3:],{a:i[0]+V[j]for i in t[1:]for j,a in enumerate(i[3:])},'',0,0,0,{'し':'shi','ち':'chi','つ':'tsu','ふ':'fu'},{'し':'ji','ち':'ji','つ':'dzu'},{'k':'g','s':'z','t':'d','h':'b'},{'ゃ':'ya','ゅ':'yu','ょ':'yo'}
 k['ん']='n'
 for i in s:
  if i in v:d+=(w:=V[v.index(i)])
  if(W:=l.get(i,k.get(i))):d+=(w:=(W[0]*(t+1)+W[1:]));t=0
  if'゛'==i and u!='ふ':d=d[:-1*len(w)]+(w:=q.get(u,g.get(w[0],w[0])+w[1]));I=1
  if'゜'==i:d=d[:-1*len(w)]+(w:='p'*len(w[:-1])+w[-1])
  if i in j:d=d[:-1*len(w)]+(w:=w[:-1]+j[i][i in['し','ち']:])
  if i=='っ':t=1
  u=i
 return d
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVTdShtBFL7fp5h6M7tmKgZvypZ5gL6AXmz3InY3ySRxE5NZUxXBGa1VU5E2lFK0iCgi9g@EQKHQPsx5kPScWf@qssue73znZ36/7SzrejubedbpjuflxMQEYwyMBbMJZgvMNphdrxkiNQCzB2YfzHswQ69H1Ecwn8B8BnMA5ouniToCcwzmFMwZmHMvI@oCzFcw38B8B/PDqxP1E8wlmBGYX2B@ewtE/QHzF@w6WAPWestI2U1YR3/Lfbe9LlE7YHfBDsC@A7vn9Ynap3jx2g9uRDvEZYyTtMqqfi8IPTYreUXlaZt7bEk0RSJy0RdatMSiqImG9HUo56d6nZbSPn@Z8SCIpuNoJozFaiVUiEuzUSOutrtMMZUxHZVD5zVEhfw0yxfSbkWnvqKiYE1wLqbds8pxh3jIe3XFBeJjxK@u8Cli3csdHiGu5nztpqBxm9@4TU9Wipwm4hqyPbQraDXF0NbRzhdd7Abi5QqV2jcE3UD2LcE2X/NYM0J3yGPJM9yWm8X1cLuYqhbOUpiUpN8P5Wy0NKWyJH3tqyAOXIY/F8rWVC3VvhLNwgZBcF3gz@G2Tfq6VA5Kc7RfQfBcy2lXieMecCkVq2QJy5/IYv2JTKLwaXmylWZ@P4hL1GXR9c1Fzdk@thT0CUr9qEwdX8jydcdD6vhoE97hhU8RV0vmziobj5YV6aVGpOKI0iJ3MsWhxOFNA0nTP@GhdlPJpfJYN9V5N2PJuNNVmfarPnd6OserjVfLu8Ne0oVGYVnUz8W92MBpafAwgFo6QdXgkun8/o8duVabpFQEdsPp9QzznFY3SXjE3y8buWZO3RTecVIcXrlUc0gqpxDOZ@j@C@cuNLwmRw9m78a5GpAmfIYZ438)